# rails 3: using ID from many-to-many table to do another query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table with contacts, a table with events, and a joining table with contact_id and event_id to map their many-to-many relationship.

I'm new to RoR and I'm used to querying the first table, building a set of IDs and running a query on the second table where id IN setofids. Is that how its done in RoR as well?

Here's what I have so far:

```
def view
 @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
 @contactevents = Contacts_Event.where(:contact_id => params[:contact_id])

 s1 = Set.new 
@contactevents.each do |contactevent| 
  s1.add(contactevent.event_id)
end

 @contactevents_test = Event.where(:id => @s1)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that is one way to do it but really you are looking at the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association [(guide here)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association). The idea is that when you do `@contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])` it will automatically pull all of the associated `Contacts_Events` as well with one query.